# Can I build a player activated fill clock in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to keep a fill clock deactivated, then have a player start it with say, a pressure plate or trip wire? It would be like a toggled off redstone clock, but with command blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need the fill clock. Just connect your signal source (Pressure plate or anything else) with a Repeat command block. The repeat command block (version 1.9+) will have the command you want. Repeat command blocks execute the command they have each tick (20x a second) when powered with Redstone signal.

Answer (score 1):

**This is 1.8/1.9/1.10 compatible**

What you are trying to accomplish requires 5 steps (in my solution):

1. The Input
2. A mono-stable circut
3. A T-Flip flop
4. A selector
5. The fill clock (output)

### The input

First, the input. The input in your case is a tripwire. This activates the toggle, and makes everything happen.

### Mono-stable circut

The input leads to a mono-stable circut. This converts the redstone signal the tripwire outputs into a one tick pulse, which is critical to the next step.

### T-Flip flop

The T-Flip flop changes the one tick pulse into a constant redstone signal, much like a lever outputs a constant signal as long as it is pulled. The T-flip flop is merely a sticky piston which pushes a blocks in one of 2 positions, depending on which state it is currently in. Like the name suggests, it flips between the 2 positions every time it gets an input.

### The selector

The selector takes the block position from the T-Flip flop, and converts it into something useful. In this case, toggling between an on fill clock and an off fill clock. There are 3 command blocks, one for an off state, and two for the on state. The off state works by placing a redstone block on one of the fill clock command blocks, therefore locking the position of the clock, ergo turning it off.

The command block contains the code `/setblock ~ ~2 ~-2 minecraft:redstone_block`.

It then turns it on by removing that redstone block `/setblock ~-1 ~1 ~-1 air`(this is the top command block), and placing another one on the fill clock, which turns it back on `/setblock ~1 ~1 ~-2 minecraft:redstone_block`.

### The fill clock

This is your typical run of the mill command block, with the bottom command block executing `/fill ~ ~1 ~ ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:air`and the other `/fill ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:redstone_block`.

---

Below is a diagram of everything.

[image: A diagram]

### The selector in more detail

The selector uses the T-Flip flops' constant output and 2 state mechanic. When the T-Flip flop gets a one tick pulse (created by the M-S circut), it activates a sticky piston, which pushes a block out. Because it is one tick, the block doesn't get retracted back, and will only go back when it is activated again. This turns the trip wire into a lever, and 2 redstone torches make it so that both positions activate something: on and off. When the wool is touching the piston, it activates a command block which turns it off (explained above). In the other state it turns it on. The reason why there are 2 command blocks, is because one deletes the block placed by the off state and the other places a redstone block in the clock, activating it again. Take note that one of the command blocks has a delay (`/setblock ~1 ~1 ~-2 minecraft:redstone_block`) and this is so that it waits for the redstone block beside the clock the be deleted first, otherwise the mechanism wouldn't have worked.

---

[image: on state and off state]